# Как скомпоновать столбцы .txt файлов в один CSV файл без модуля Pandas?

Tags: python, csv, txt

У меня есть 7 файлов .txt со значениями. Значения записаны в 1 столбец. Количество строк во всех файлах одинаково. Я хочу собрать все файлы в один CSV.

Начало моего кода:

```
import csv    
output_file_name = "./values/values.csv"
csvfile = open(outfilename, "w")
title = "Name,Value,Target,Condition,Dimension,Description,Comments,"
csvfile.write(title)
```

В первую строку я записал название столбцов, именно в таком порядке должны располагаться данные.

Может кто-нибудь помочь?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

воспользуйтесь стандартным модулем [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

filenames = ["1.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt"]
output_file_name = "values.csv"
title = "Name,Value,Target,Condition,Dimension,Description,Comments"
sep = ","

files = [open(f) for f in filenames]

with open(output_file_name, "w") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=sep)
    writer.writerow(title.split(sep))
    for row in zip(*files):
        writer.writerow(map(str.strip, row))

_ = [f.close() for f in files]
```

PS  решение с использованием модуля Pandas было бы гораздо более элегантным...

---

**UPD:** для сравнения - решение с использованием Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

filenames = ["1.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt", ..., "7.txt"]
output_file_name = "values.csv"
title = "Name,Value,Target,Condition,Dimension,Description,Comments"
sep = ","

(pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, header=None) for f in filenames], axis=1)
   .set_axis(title.split(sep), axis=1)
   .to_csv(output_file_name))
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Но только строки с числами чередуются с пустыми строками.

Comment: @BaurzhanKuzhahmetov, у меня все правильно отрабатывает. Попробуйте привести в вопросе [mcve]